# Getting "function did not throw" While Testing Async Function to Throw Error with Jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to test an async function with Jest and I can't get my test to pass.

My Code

```js
export class UnexpectedRequestError {
  constructor(public message: string = 'Unauthorized') {
    this.message = message;
  }
}

export const foo = async (arg: boolean) => {
  if (arg) {
    return true;
  } else {
    const message = 'message';
    await sendSlackMessage(message);
    throw new UnexpectedRequestError(message);
  }
};
```

Test Code

```js
test('throws UnexpectedRequestError', async () => {
  await expect(foo(false)).rejects.toThrow(UnexpectedRequestError);
});
```

My test returns:

```bash
expect(received).rejects.toThrow(expected)

Expected constructor: UnexpectedRequestError

Received function did not throw
```

I've searched for other similar questions here on StackOverFlow but I couldn't find anything wrong with my codes. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `except(() => foo(false))`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. `await expect(() => foo(false)).rejects.toThrow(UnexpectedRequestError)` gave me the same result, which is `Received function did not throw`.

Comment: Make sure that your function will be call with actual logic in your test.

Comment: @hoangdv I've tried putting `console.log('abc')` right before `throw new UnexpectedRequestError(message)` and `abc` gets displayed when I run the test. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, it seem something went wrong. Let's try to call `await foo();` before the assertion line.

Comment: @hoangdv https://stackoverflow.com/a/73739678/10421404 This was it, but thanks anyway!

Comment: FWIW, here's a relevant github issue: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/12024

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error class needs the "Error" inheritance.

```
export class UnexpectedRequestError extends Error {
  constructor(public message: string = 'Unauthorized') {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. But is there any other method to solve this? In here `throw new Error(err);` I am getting this error as I am using ts.  `No overload matches this call.`

Comment: You can use your error class, exemple ```throw new UnexpectedRequestError(err);```, maybe worked without this another error.